# WiX major upgrade refuses to replace existing file!

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

**EDIT!**

It's rough how a question on here seems to get seen when first posted, but when a question is asked, and then answered, for me it seems abandoned.  I am still having this problem, and not sure what to do.

Hello!  I have inherited this project with a WiX installer, and am required to make this version usefully upgrade the previous one!  My problem comes in replacing the database files with new versions.  No, the problem is not that they are locked, I can replace them manually, and in fact now ONE of them is replaced, while the other is not.  Please, please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.  I've tried several other solutions (including registry keys as KeyPath instead of CompanionFile) but nothing is quite working.

Here is (most of) the code of the .WXS file:

```
<Product Id='$(var.ProductCode)'
    UpgradeCode='$(var.UpgradeCode)'
    Name="Pathways"
    Version='$(var.ProductVersion)'
    Manufacturer='$(var.Manufacturer)'
    Language='1033'>


    <Package Id="*" 
     Description="Pathways Directory Software"
     InstallerVersion="301"
     Compressed="yes" />

    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="License.rtf" />
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="Pathways.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
        <UpgradeVersion
    OnlyDetect="no"  
    Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)"
    IncludeMaximum="no"
    Language="1033"
    Property="OLDAPPFOUND"
   />
        <UpgradeVersion
    Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)"
    IncludeMinimum="yes"
    OnlyDetect="no"
    Language="1033"
    Property="NEWAPPFOUND"
   />
    </Upgrade>

    <Property Id="ALLUSERS">2</Property>

    <!-- directories -->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">

        <!-- program files directory -->
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Pathways"/>
        </Directory>

        <!-- application data directory -->
        <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder" Name="CommonAppData">
            <Directory Id="CommonAppDataPathways" Name="Pathways" />
        </Directory>

        <!-- start menu program directory -->
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
            <Directory Id="ProgramsMenuPathwaysFolder" Name="Pathways" />
        </Directory>

        <!-- desktop directory -->
        <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" />

    </Directory>

    <Icon Id="PathwaysIcon" SourceFile="\\Fileserver\Release\Pathways\Latest\Release\Pathways.exe" />

    <!-- components in the reference to the install directory -->
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
        <Component Id="Application" Guid="EEE4EB55-A515-4872-A4A5-06D6AB4A06A6">
            <File Id="pathwaysExe" Name="Pathways.exe" DiskId="1" Source="\\Fileserver\Release\Pathways\Latest\Release\Pathways.exe" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" Assembly=".net" AssemblyApplication="pathwaysExe" AssemblyManifest="pathwaysExe">
                <!--<netfx:NativeImage Id="ngen_Pathways.exe" Platform="32bit" Priority="2"/> -->
            </File>

            <File Id="pathwaysChm" Name="Pathways.chm" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\Pathways.chm" />

            <File Id="publicKeyXml" ShortName="RSAPUBLI.XML" Name="RSAPublicKey.xml" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\RSAPublicKey.xml" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="staticListsXml" ShortName="STATICLI.XML" Name="StaticLists.xml" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\StaticLists.xml" Vital="yes" />

            <File Id="axInteropMapPointDll" ShortName="AXMPOINT.DLL" Name="AxInterop.MapPoint.dll" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\AxInterop.MapPoint.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="interopMapPointDll" ShortName="INMPOINT.DLL" Name="Interop.MapPoint.dll" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\Interop.MapPoint.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="mapPointDll" ShortName="MAPPOINT.DLL" Name="MapPoint.dll" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\Interop.MapPoint.dll" Vital="yes" />

            <File Id="devExpressData63Dll" ShortName="DAAT63.DLL" Name="DevExpress.Data.v6.3.dll" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\DevExpress.Data.v6.3.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="devExpressUtils63Dll" ShortName="UTILS63.DLL" Name="DevExpress.Utils.v6.3.dll" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\DevExpress.Utils.v6.3.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="devExpressXtraBars63Dll" ShortName="BARS63.DLL" Name="DevExpress.XtraBars.v6.3.dll" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\DevExpress.XtraBars.v6.3.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="devExpressXtraNavBar63Dll" ShortName="NAVBAR63.DLL" Name="DevExpress.XtraNavBar.v6.3.dll" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\DevExpress.XtraNavBar.v6.3.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="devExpressXtraCharts63Dll" ShortName="CHARTS63.DLL" Name="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v6.3.dll" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\DevExpress.XtraCharts.v6.3.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="devExpressXtraEditors63Dll" ShortName="EDITOR63.DLL" Name="DevExpress.XtraEditors.v6.3.dll" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\DevExpress.XtraEditors.v6.3.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="devExpressXtraPrinting63Dll" ShortName="PRINT63.DLL" Name="DevExpress.XtraPrinting.v6.3.dll" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\DevExpress.XtraPrinting.v6.3.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="devExpressXtraReports63Dll" ShortName="REPORT63.DLL" Name="DevExpress.XtraReports.v6.3.dll" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\DevExpress.XtraReports.v6.3.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="devExpressXtraRichTextEdit63Dll" ShortName="RICHTE63.DLL" Name="DevExpress.XtraRichTextEdit.v6.3.dll" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\DevExpress.XtraRichTextEdit.v6.3.dll" Vital="yes" />

            <RegistryValue Id="PathwaysInstallDir" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Tribal Data Resources\Pathways" Name="InstallDir" Action="write" Type="string" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" />
        </Component>

    </DirectoryRef>

    <!-- application data components -->
    <DirectoryRef Id="CommonAppDataPathways">

        <Component Id="CommonAppDataPathwaysFolderComponent" Guid="087C6F14-E87E-4B57-A7FA-C03FC8488E0D">
            <CreateFolder>
                <Permission User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />
            </CreateFolder>

            <RemoveFolder Id="CommonAppDataPathways" On="uninstall" />
            <!-- <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\TDR\Pathways" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />-->

        </Component>

        <Component Id="Settings" Guid="A3513208-4F12-4496-B609-197812B4A953" NeverOverwrite="yes">
            <File Id="settingsXml" KeyPath="yes" ShortName="SETTINGS.XML" Name="Settings.xml" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\Settings\settings.xml" Vital="yes" />   
        </Component>


        <Component Id="Database" Guid="1D8756EF-FD6C-49BC-8400-299492E8C65D" >
            <!-- <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="Software\TDR\Pathways\Database" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" /> -->
            <File Id="pathwaysMdf" Name="Pathways.mdf" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Shared\Databases\Pathways\SystemDBs\Pathways.mdf" CompanionFile="pathwaysExe" Vital="yes"/>
            <File Id="pathwaysLdf" Name="Pathways_log.ldf" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Shared\Databases\Pathways\SystemDBs\Pathways.ldf" CompanionFile="pathwaysExe" Vital="yes"/>

        </Component>



        <!--
   <Component Id="MDF" Guid="FFB7CE02-B592-4c44-A315-99CF4828E3D9" >
    <File Id="pathwaysMdf" KeyPath="yes" Name="Pathways.mdf" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Shared\Databases\Pathways\SystemDBs\Pathways.mdf" />
   </Component>

   <Component Id="LDF" Guid="9E4E3DCA-A067-47f4-9905-4AD5C35A8025" >
    <File Id="pathwaysLdf" KeyPath="yes" Name="Pathways_log.ldf" DiskId="1" Source="\\fileserver\Shared\Databases\Pathways\SystemDBs\Pathways.ldf" />
   </Component>
   -->
    </DirectoryRef>

    <!-- shortcut components -->
    <DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
        <Component Id="DesktopShortcutComponent" Guid="1BF412BA-9C6B-460D-80ED-8388AC66703F">
            <Shortcut Id="DesktopShortcut"
        Target="[INSTALLDIR]Pathways.exe"
        Name="Pathways"
        Description="Pathways Tribal Directory"
        Icon="PathwaysIcon"
        Show="normal"
        WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" />
            <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\TDR\Pathways" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <DirectoryRef Id ="ProgramsMenuPathwaysFolder">
        <Component Id="ProgramsMenuShortcutComponent" Guid="83A18245-4C22-4CDC-94E0-B480F80A407D">
            <Shortcut Id="ProgramsMenuShortcut" Target="[INSTALLDIR]Pathways.exe" Name="Pathways" Icon="PathwaysIcon" Show="normal" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" />
            <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramsMenuPathwaysFolder" On="uninstall"/>
            <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\TDR\Pathways" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>


    <Feature Id="App" Title="Pathways Application" Level="1" Description="Pathways software" Display="expand" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Absent="disallow" AllowAdvertise="no" InstallDefault="local">
        <ComponentRef Id="Application" />
        <ComponentRef Id="CommonAppDataPathwaysFolderComponent" />
        <ComponentRef Id="Settings"/>
        <ComponentRef Id="ProgramsMenuShortcutComponent" />
        <Feature Id="Shortcuts" Title="Desktop Shortcut" Level="1" Absent="allow" AllowAdvertise="no" InstallDefault="local">
            <ComponentRef Id="DesktopShortcutComponent" />
        </Feature>
    </Feature>


    <Feature Id="Data" Title="Database" Level="1" Absent="allow" AllowAdvertise="no" InstallDefault="local">
        <ComponentRef Id="Database" />
    </Feature>

    <UIRef Id ="WixUI_FeatureTree"/>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText"/>

    <UI>
        <Error Id="2000">There is a later version of this program installed.</Error>
    </UI>

    <CustomAction Id="NewerVersionDetected" Error="2000" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallFinalize"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

</Product>
```

Running this installer attempting the upgrade from the previous version ALMOST WORKS.  The file that is giving me trouble is the one called "PathwaysMdf".  Even though it's Component code is EXACTLY the same as the PathwaysLdf file, that file is replaced, while the MDF is NOT.  You can see, commented out, some of the other things I've attempted, some from suggestions on stackoverflow.

The entire log file from running the upgrade is located at:
http://pastebin.com/ppjhq6Wi

THANK YOU!
Joshua

Comment: Just mentioning that the path: `\\fileserver\Release\Pathways\Dependencies\ ` could be replaced with defined variable as well...

Answer (score 2):

Are you following the [component rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa370561)?

Why are you not using one file per component? Multiple files in a component gets very ugly, very quickly.

(Note that this isn't really a WiX issue, but more likely to be a Windows Installer issue due to violation of component rules)

Comment: I can find nowhere in these component rules that I should have one file per component.  The LDF and MDF files go together, and are useless without each other, so it seems to make sense to me to have them as one component.  Even though they're one component, one of them is overwriting properly and the other is not.

Reading these rules does not reveal where I've broken them.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you setting the CompanionFile attribute for those files to "pathwaysExe"? In doing so, you are asking Windows Installer to base the decision to update those files on whether or not "pathwaysExe" is also updated. Since the version of "pathwaysExe" has not changed (and thus Windows Installer won't updated it), the other files are likewise not updated.

By the way, you say that the .ldf file *is* updated...Are you sure? The log file you posted indicates otherwise.

Comment: I set the CompanionFile because the MDF and LDF files are unversioned, and PathwaysExe is versioned.  PathwaysExe IS being updated, it's the main executable of the application.

And yes, I'm QUITE certain that the LDF file is being updated... i'll re-check right now though.

Comment: YES, the PathwaysExe and PathwaysLdf files are DEFINITELY being updated, and the PathwaysMdf file is disappearing after upgrade.

You can see why I'm so confused.  ;)